# setcookie() always returns true, even when browser cookies are disabled

Tags: php, cookies

why is this if statement always true? Even if i disable cookies in browser, it tells me "Cookie was set." print_r prints empty array, but it should say "No Cookie could be set, please allow cookies."

What's wrong with my code?

```
if (setcookie("Testcookie", "values of cookie", time()+3600*24))   // 1h*24 = 24hours
   {
        echo ("Cookie was set. ");
        print_r ($_COOKIE);
} else {
        echo("No Cookie could be set, please allow cookies.");
}
```

UPDATE: i tried this:

```
setcookie("Testcookie", "values of cookie", time()+3600*24);    // 1h*24 = 24hours

if ((isset($_COOKIE)) && (!empty($_COOKIE))) { print_r($_COOKIE);} else {echo("No Cookie found.");}
```

This sets Cookie correctly, but it says "No Cookie found". After one reload it finds Cookie and print_r it. Why does it take one reload? I didn't send anything prior setcookie() call. Cookie IS set, but on first reload after deleting/enabling cookies it is not shown.

Comment: “[If output exists prior to calling this function, `setcookie()` will fail and return **FALSE**. If `setcookie()` successfully runs, it will return **TRUE**. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.](http://php.net/setcookie)”

Comment: `setcookie` has no way of knowing if the browser will *ignore* the cookie (which is what disabling cookies in a browser does); it only sets the appropriate cookie header for the response.

Comment: I replaced above code with this: 
setcookie("Testcookie", "values of cookie", time()+3600*24);    // 1h*24 = 24hours

        
if ((isset($_COOKIE)) && (!empty($_COOKIE))) { print_r($_COOKIE);} else {echo("No Cookie found.");}

Comment: But this doesn't work for very first reload after enabling and deleting cookies. When page is first loaded, it sets cookie and says "No cookie found." After one reload it print_r array of cookie. This is strange, it shouldn't take reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setcookie()` will always successfully create the cookie unless headers have already been sent [(see Gumbo's link in the comments)](https://www.php.net/setcookie). It doesn't get feedback from the browser as to whether or not it was accepted. You need to set a flag that shows you attempted to set the cookie and then check to see if you get that cookie back on a new page request. Only then, when the cookie is not present, can you be sure that the cookie is not being accepted.